# Empty $_POST variables in PHP AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I encountered a problem when performing an AJAX POST request in my PHP code when the `$_POST` `$name` and `$age` variables are empty. I've looked through my code, but I can't determine the cause of the problem. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

In my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>AJAX POST Example</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>AJAX POST Example</h1>
  
  <form id="myForm">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>
    
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age"><br><br>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  
  <div id="result"></div>
  
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting normally
        
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var age = $('#age').val();
        
        var data = {
          name: name,
          age: age
        };
        
        // Send the AJAX request
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'test.php',
          data: data,
          success: function(response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my `test.php` file:

```
<?php
  
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $age = $_POST['age'];
  
  $response = "Name: $name<br>";
  $response .= "Age: $age<br>";
  $response .= "This is the result from the server.";
  
  // Return the response as JSON
  echo json_encode($response);
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

The steps I took to fix the problem:

1. Made sure that the jQuery library is properly included in the `index.html` file.
2. Made sure the form inputs had the correct id and name attributes.
3. Used `event.preventDefault()` in the JavaScript code to prevent the form from being submitted normally.
4. Checked the web tab in the browser developer tools for errors or problems in the AJAX request.
5. Verified that the `test.php` file is in the same directory as the `index.html` file.
6. Made sure my local web server (Nginx) is properly configured to handle PHP files.

I see the correct result in sending an ajax request to `index.html`. Despite these efforts, the `$name` and `$age` variables in my PHP code remain blank when the AJAX POST request is executed. I searched for a solution to this problem on the SO but nothing worked for me. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Comment: What kind of data did you see sent in the browser developer tools?

Comment: @shingo The result of sending the form `index.html` is correct . But when I open the `test.php` page the variables are empty. You can check test.bethub.win/index.html test.bethub.win/test.php

Comment: _"But when I open ..."_, that makes sense. The post data are not persistent, they are only available for the request. If you want them to maintain, learn how to use [session](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) or [database](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp).

Comment: Posting `test.bethub.win/test.php` for us to test makes no sense, `$_POST` will be NULL when calling the page from your address bar

Comment: Cannot reproduce, form data is correctly sent to the page and the output seems to be as expected

Answer (score -3):

**Try with formdata like below :**

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting normally
        
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        
        // Send the AJAX request
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'test.php',
          data: formData,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function(response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: That won't make a difference. Testing the OP's original code shows it works. (The comments have drawn out the real problem, which is that the OP is expecting the data to persist and show up on subsequent GET requests to the same URL).